# Why aren't they using the "link" to give the robots instructions?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-robot

At the end of *I, Robot* the N5s are told to "report for storage" over an old school loudspeaker. The robots still appear to be linked through a central system, why aren't they using that to communicate with the robots?

Comment: Wasn't the link simply to upgrade their software? I don't remember it specifically being used for new communication. But whether I'm right or wrong about that, this also makes it easier for the audience watching the movie to understand what's going on -- and makes it seem more draconian.

Comment: It occured to me that it might be purely for the audience, but they repeated it a dozen times... *prone to exagerate*